# Authenticate users on my site through LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm working on a small site for my university. The requirements include the ability for our users to authenticate with their LinkedIn accounts. I know Facebook and Twitter have such capability, but what about LinkedIn? I'll be doing this in .NET, is there a native SDK?

Thanks,
Sara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinkedIn uses OAuth just like Facebook, their developer site / docs are at:

http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1243

Answer (score 1):

javascript api:
http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1225

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1190) is simple OAuth C# working example and ASP.NET implementation example project.

It will help you in LinkedIn implementation.